# Resources not copied to output path in IntelliJ 12.1.4

Tags: intellij-idea

I seem to have done something to tell IntelliJ to not copy source resources (e.g. XML and property files) to the compiler output folder.

Resources are not being copied to the Compiler output path. **Test** resources are copied to the test ouput folder, but no **source** resources are copied.

**Source folder:** `src`

(this is `C:\dev\myproject\src` and contains XML files)

**Test Source folder:** `tests\integration\src`

(this is `C:\dev\myproject\tests\integration\src` and contains XML files)

**Compiler output:**

- Use module compile output path
- Output path: `C:\dev\myproject\build\classes`
- Test output path: `C:\dev\myproject\build\test`

Settings -> Compiler -> Resource patterns: 
`?*.properties;?*.xml;?*.gif;?*.png;?*.jpeg;?*.jpg;?*.html;?*.dtd;?*.tld;?*.ftl`

This is preventing me from running integration tests which load files from the classpath. (I do not have full control over the structure of this legacy project and most of the other developers use Eclipse.)

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what I need to do in order to have IntelliJ copy the resource to the output folders?

Comment: If it's not a Maven project, it should work fine, otherwise it's a bug that [needs to be reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the sample project to reproduce. As a workaround you can try to [disable external build](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png), but it's not recommended.

Comment: I already had [Use external build](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/1856/intellijcompilersetting.jpg) selected. I have unticked it and it is now working! But there are a couple of other devs that do use IntelliJ, and they have it ticked and the resources are copied as expected.

Comment: If you have a test case, report a bug.

Comment: I am experiencing same issue: test resources are not copied to output folder.

Comment: In my attempt to create a test case for CrazyCoder, I restarted IntelliJ and that seemed to fix my issue! So I failed to recreate my problem. Sorry, I cant help you more than suggest restarting IntelliJ as that's what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

i had same problems with IntelliJ IDEA 13 using Maven.

i solved it by adding this to my ***build*** tag in the pom.xml file:

```
<build>
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/com</directory>
    <targetPath>com</targetPath>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
...
</build>
```

change path according to your project. More about the [Maven Resources Plugin here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue. Idea seems to have a bug in projects with maven dependencies.

The workarounds I could found so far:

1. Disable the external build.
2. Generate an ant build script (Idea does this for you) and compile with that script.

Once you have successfully created your artifacts with either way, Idea continues to use them until the next maven dependency change.

Comment: For those using IntelliJ IDEA 13, external build is the only option available since the older compiler has been removed. Thus, you won't find any checkbox for "Use external build" and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

When using Gradle, try adding the resources to the `sourceSets` (use below code when you have the resource files in the same folder as the source files, otherwise adapt the path)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs 'test'
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs 'test'
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to [How do I add resources to sourceSet with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732206/how-do-i-add-resources-to-sourceset-with-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of jpa when you add a jpa facet, Intellij creates:

```
META-INF/persistence.xml under src/main/java
```

But it does not update the build

Added this to pom.xml to fix the problem:

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/java</directory>
  <includes>
     <include>**/*.xml</include>
  </includes>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```