# How do I add resources to sourceSet with gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Currently I have the following build.gradle file:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/model'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'images/model' 
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'tests/model'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'images/model' // <=== NOT WORKING
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/mnist-tools.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

My repository if here: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

and 4 out of my 49 tests are failing because the tests in folder "tests/model" need a file within the folder "images/model". How do I add the resources correctly? Thanks!

Comment: The linked repository has been deleted. I can't see the project structure to understand the answers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had a closer look at your build.gradle and it seems that paths are a little bit off.

You specify source as `src/model`, yet your project structure and Java source suggest that `model` is your package name, which means the source declaration should be:

```
main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
    }
}
```

Same for tests:

```
test {
    java {
        srcDir 'tests'
    }
}
```

Now, with missing resources. In your code you are using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName))`
`getClass().getResource()` is using relative path to the resource. To keep the resources on the same level, you should update declaration for the resources and remove `model`:

```
test {
    java {
        srcDir 'tests'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir 'images'
    }
}
```

You might also need to run

```
./gradlew clean
```

before it works.

Here's the result with the updated build.gradle:

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 19):

The syntax used in your build script is correct. It's not clear to me why you add the same resource directory to both source sets, and why you claim that it isn't working in one case.

`srcDir "foo"` adds another directory. If you instead want to replace the default directory, use `srcDirs = [ "foo" ]` instead. However, this won't solve the problem at hand.

It would be good to see the code that loads the resources, to rule out any problems with that.

Comment: I cannot copy and paste it but if you clone my repo and run gradle build you will see it.