# Not able to find *.xml file under Intellij

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to running some unit test cases that need to read spring xml configurations under Intellij, but Intellij failed with the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [test.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Under Intellij, my folder structure is:

```
src/main/java
src/main/test
src/main/spring
```

and text.xml file is under src/main/spring

The related java code that loads configuration file is:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml")
```

I have searched for several posts and I have tried the following ways:

```
1) marked src/main/spring folder as "sources" or "resources".
2) added src/main/spring as a module under project structure.
```

but unfortunately, none of them is working.

My sourceSets in build.gradle setting is:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        proto {
            // In addition to the default "src/main/proto"
            srcDir "src/main/proto"
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/test'
        }

        proto {
            srcDir "src/main/proto"
        }
    }
}
```

I am a newbie to Gradle and hopefully someone could give me a hint. Really appreciate!

Comment: `src/main/spring` needs to be added to the `resources`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737466/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder This works perfectly. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `src/main/spring` to the `resources` in `build.gradle` file, see the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737466/104891).

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
 ...
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/spring'
        }
 ...
    }
}
```