# Spring Boot integration tests cannot reach application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have some classes annotated with `@RestController` that I'm trying to test using the `MockMvc` class. The end-points respond properly from a web application, but I get the following error when running the tests (from IntelliJ IDEA):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
'spring.data.rest.base-path' in string value "${spring.data.rest.base-path}/whatever"
```

This is how the `application.properties` file looks like:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
spring.profiles.active=dev
...
```

I also have a file called `application-dev.properties` with additional (different) properties.

This is how the test classes are annotated:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest // Also tried: @WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
// Also tried: @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
// Also tried: @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MyRestControllerTest {
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, this is how the REST controllers are implemented (where the problematic property is being used):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${spring.data.rest.base-path}/whatever")
public class MyRestController {
    ...
}
```

This is how the application's main class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {...})
@EnableJpaRepositories({...})
@EntityScan({...})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is (a subset of) the project's structure:

```
my-project
|_ src
   |_ java
   |  |_ com.example.x
   |     |_ controller
   |        |_ MyRestController.java
   |
   |_ test
   |  |_ com.example.x
   |     |_ controller
   |        |_ MyRestControllerTest.java
   |
   |_ resources
      |_ application.properties
      |_ application-dev.properties
```

I've found several solutions to the problem throughout the web, but none of them seemed to work for me.

Comment: i didn't see where you used this property

Comment: Sorry, you are right I didn't clarify that. It is being used in the REST controllers to define the base path for all the end-points. There the property is doing just fine -- as I mentioned, I can access them from a browser as expected. The only place it cannot be read from are the tests.

Comment: It seems like Intellij did not recognize /resources as resources folder. Try @PropertySource('file:/path/to/application.properties')

Answer (score 2):

The answer was finally not related with Spring annotations nor IntelliJ configuration, but rather with `MockMvc` and, in particular, with the class and method `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup`, which was being used on the tests' `setUp`. This would not use the application's context, thus not being able to properly read properties which depend on it.

After changing it to `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup`, which (from the docs)

> Build[s] a MockMvc instance using the given, fully initialized (i.e.,
>   refreshed) WebApplicationContext.

everything worked fine. For integration tests, it makes more sense to use this, doesn't it?

Thanks to all for your time and effort. Sorry for not showing the mentioned `setUp` method, but I didn't imagine the problem could have been caused there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.properties` must not be on the test classpath. You should define a "Test Resources" location for your project in IntelliJ and create an `application.properties` file there.

BTW, I've found it to be useful to have a separate test properties file, since test properties are typically different than the normal run-time environment.

Comment: I've tried to mark the resources folder as "Test Resources Root" on IntelliJ, but that didn't help.

Comment: When you look at the actual files in the test classpath, what do you see? Unfortunately, I've never used IntelliJ so I have limited insight there. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039653/resources-not-copied-to-output-path-in-intellij-12-1-4 helps?