# .lib resources not copied to "out" folder for gradle tests in Intellij

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle, resources

Similar to: [Resources not copied to output path in IntelliJ 12.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039653/resources-not-copied-to-output-path-in-intellij-12-1-4), I am finding that any resource with an extension of "*.lib" is ignored by Intellij (community 2017.2) when copying resource files into the `/out` directory managed by Intellij for Gradle projects.

I try adding liberal includes to my `/build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets.test.resources {
  srcDirs = ["src/test/resources"]
  includes = ["**/*"]
}
```

but everything but the `*.lib` files are copied into the `/out/test/resources/**/*.*` location upon refreshing the gradle project. In troubleshooting, I confirmed that if I change the extension of a file from `*.lib` to something else (such as `*.txt`), Intellij correctly copies the file into `/out/resources/**/*.txt`. I can also manually copy the `*.lib` files into `out/resources/**/*.lib` and it won't remove them (a work around).

How can `*.lib` files be automatically copied from the `test/resources/**/*.lib` to `/out/test/resources/**/*.lib` in Intellij for running gradle unit tests?

Comment: I'm having this issue, did you find out how to copy the test resources to the out folder?